# Why is my custom Swift class not transferring to my GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to be able to access my custom class in my game scene. I followed the directions at: http://spritekitlessons.com/how-to-write-your-own-custom-classes-in-sprite-kit/

First I create a new file called Player.swift, I make sure its targeted into my project folder

then I add this custom class

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    let walkingActive = 0 
}
```

But when I try to access it in my gameScene

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var thePlayer: Player = Player()

 }
```

I get the error: **Use of undeclared type 'Player'**

if I try to instantiate the class with a type that isn't being recognized like this

```
 if let somePlayer:Player = self.childNode(withName: "Player") as? Player {
               //make the declared variable equal to somePlayer
               thePlayer = somePlayer
    
           }
```

I get the errors:

**Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '<>'**

**Use of undeclared type 'Player'**

I'm following the guide exactly and i've found another resource which tells me to do the exact same thing. So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks

Here are pictures of exactly what I'm doing for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like target membership issue.

I suggest that look at the target membership of Player.swift and make sure that the check mark next to your project name is there.

**How to verify target membership**

1. Click on the file
2. Open the Utility Pane (The right pane on Xcode) *(option + command + 0)*
3. Navigate to the File Inspector in the Utility Pane (The file icon)
4. Target membership and file path should be listed

[image]